# Why does my Windows 8 laptop have issues connecting wirelessly to my primary network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, router

My primary network is a WPA2 AES secured router. Two cell phones and a Windows 7 laptop connect to it without issue.

When I try to access my network via a Windows 8 laptop (with the right password), I get a “Can’t connect to network” error. My wireless card IPv4 settings are set on automatic (DHCP) settings like all my other devices. This laptop can connect to other wireless networks flawlessly.  Why does this device have issues?

Comment: Just for context - what router? What's the laptop?

Comment: The router was a D-Link DIR-615 and the Laptop is an Asus K55 (If I'm not mistaken, it's been a while). We have not been able to solve the problem, although the laptop is able to connect on several other DIR-615 routers. I could not troubleshoot it anymore, since I moved a few months ago.